# C/C++ REGS union in DOS.h no longer available. Any alternatives?

Tags: c++

I've had to use a very old library written some twenty years ago.  I get it to compile almost completely, except for one part that uses a REGS union.  From the Google searching I've done, REGS is a part of interrupt handling in the DOS.h file.  Well, looking at the modern version of DOS.h, one does not see any REGS definition.

Some posts around the Internet said something about it being unique to either the Borland or Turbo compilers, but this code was written to work under many different compilers.

Any ideas what I should do?  Is an old DOS.h file floating around that might work?

Using: Visual Studio 2010, compiling from command line.

Comment: And you need this for what, exactly? You're not writing 16-bit code any more.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus No, I'm not writing 16-bit code.  But I want to avoid changing the code, if possible.  The code is an old math library.  I wish I could say more, but I can't.

Comment: There are tons of modern math libraries around.. is there something all that special about this one that makes it so necessary?

Comment: @Collin Yes.  It's a weird explanation, but we needed a set of interpolation/splining functions, and this library-- while old-- provided the best solution.  I'd get into the details but that'd derail the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the only thing you can do is figure out what they're doing *with* the REGS, and do (as close as you can) to the same thing at that higher level. In most cases, REGS were used to invoke DOS functions, most of which have equivalents that can be invoked as normal functions under Windows. Others were to use BIOS functions, which (again) mostly have functions to accomplish the same.

Without knowing what was being accomplished with the REGS, however, it's impossible to guess what the replacement would/will be.

Answer (score 2):

Creating the `REGS` union is the least of your problems. Applications can't simply call interrupts whenever they want under a protected-mode operating system. And if they try, they'll be stopped by the system.

A better approach is to look for ways to accomplish it using the Windows API.

**EDIT**

The above comments assume you are doing modern-day Windows development, which I guess was an assumption. Other than the tools you are using, you really haven't said a thing about the type of application you are developing (command line, windowed, 32-bit, 64-bit, etc.), in addition to not saying anything about the task you're trying to accomplish.

If you are developing for 16-bit DOS, then you can still do interrupts.

Comment: I'm interested in compiling it into a library that can be used in a modern application (a c# application, that is).  It's a library of math functions, and really that's about it.

Comment: Well, based on the new information, I can say that interrupts are not the correct approach. Sorry, "library of math functions" doesn't provide near enough information to suggest what APIs might be helpful.