# Error incomplete type is not allowed when use union

Tags: c, unions

I just tried to test this code in visual stduio 2015:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>

void set_border(int);

void main()
{
   set_border(10);
   getch();
}
void set_border(int color)
{
   union REGS in, out;
   in.h.ah = 0x0b;
   in.h.bh = 0;
   in.h.bl = color;
   int86(0x10, &in, &out);
}
```

i want to set color border for the monitor screen but the vs show me the **"incomplete type is not allowed"** error. errors highlighted in **union REGS in, out;** and 3 next lines.

Comment: So what is `union REGS in, out;` supposed to be? - did you mean to just write `REGS in, out;`?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285266/c-c-regs-union-in-dos-h-no-longer-available-any-alternatives would help

Comment: @UnholySheep 'union REGS in, out;' is two input and output colors from register ah and bh

Comment: Looks like it cannot find the definition for **union REGS**.  Do you know which file it is defined in?  Has it beeen #ifdef'd out?

Comment: You'll need a compiler that can generate 16-bit x86 code. Examples of such compilers include [Microsoft Visual C++ 1.52c](https://archive.org/details/Microsoft_Visual_C_-_Version_1.52c_Microsoft_1995), [Borland C++ 5.02](https://archive.org/details/BorlandC5.02), and [Open Watcom C/C++](http://www.openwatcom.org/download.php).

Comment: regardless of what Visual Studio will let you get away with, the return type from `main()` is always `int`, not `void`